# count and aggregated list joining tables

Tags: sql, oracle, join, count, aggregate

I need some help for sql, the data looks like following.

```
table A (a1, a2, a3)
table B (b1, b2)
```

A.a1 and B.b1 refers each other. What I want to is that for the unique B.b1, I would like to get A.a2, which can be multiple records by referencing A.a1.
For example,

```
A
v1, v2, v3
v1, v4, v5
v1, v3, v6
v2, v7, v8

B
v1, v9
v2, v10
v1, v11
```

I would like to get the result like following including count and aggregated string.

```
v1, 3, (v2,v4,v3)
v2, 1, (v7)
```

I think this is not that complicated, for me it seems to take some time :)
If someone is familiar with this, please give some advice.

Comment: It is actually quite simple. See if you can do it yourself. The steps are: join first; then GROUP BY `B.b1`, and in the aggregation (in `SELECT`) use the functions `COUNT()` and `LISTAGG()`. **With that said**: What is your Oracle version? `LISTAGG()` has only been around since Oracle 11.2. If you don't know your version, run `select * from v$version`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select data.a1,
count(data.a1) as count,
LISTAGG(data.a2,',') WITHIN GROUP(order by data.a2 desc) as third_column from
(select A.a1,A.a2 from A where A.a1 in (select DISTINCT B.b1 from B )) data
 group by data.a1;
```

Comment: It turned out to be complicated :) It works well, thank you so much.